# Adding a key-value pair in every object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a list of objects and I want every object to be inserted by a certain key value. Please take note that it is an AngularJS `$scope`. I'm aware that this can be done by.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.Items = [
    {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
    {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
    {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'},
];
```

But what I want is to make it from that to this:

```
$scope.Items = [
    {name:'Jani',country:'Norway', edit:false},
    {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden', edit:false},
    {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark', edit:false},
];
```

Comment: A simple loop would do. Or a `.map` over the array. Is there any particular reason you haven't tried either of those?

Comment: Why not create a function that will iterate the array and add the property? It is simple JS.

Comment: Note that there is no JSON involved here. That's an array initializer containing object initializers. When you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: I am new to angularjs to answer all comments and looking for an answer that can be considered as a best practice

Answer (score 4):

A simple `forEach` or just about any other looping construct will do it:

```
$scope.Items.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.edit = false;
});
```